# How to change color in statusline if current file has no utf8 fileencoding?

Tags: vim, encoding, utf-8, statusline

I want to realize a different color in my statusline if a file has **no utf8** encoding.

This is what I use now:

```
set statusline+=%3*\ F:%{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&fileencoding} 

hi User3 guifg=#292b00  guibg=#f4f597
```

This is what I want to realize:

```
set statusline+=%{Fenc()}*\ F:%{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&fileencoding}
function! Fenc()
    if &fenc !~ "utf-8"
        return "4"
    else
        return "3"
    endif
endfunction

hi User3 guifg=#292b00  guibg=#f4f597
hi User4 guifg=#ff0000  guibg=#f4f597
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: what are you doing here: `%{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&fileencoding}` ?

Comment: @Kent, `If exists fileencoding, write it`. Is there an error in the code?

Comment: if not exist? you write it anyway or I misunderstood your logic? do you mean `&fenc?&fenc:&enc`?

Comment: @Kent, yes that's what I mean.

Comment: @Kent, Sorry 'F:' was missing before before the code (updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, in your code:

```
%{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&fileencoding}
```

makes no sense, it is like, `if a is there, I write a, otherwise I write a anyway.`

I guess you want to have `&fenc?&fenc:&enc`

I don't think you can evaluate the function and then put with `%` together with `set stl`, but you can build your function in this way:

```
hi User3 ....
hi User4 ....
function! MkStatusLine()
    if &fenc == "utf-8"     
        set statusline=%4*
    else
        set statusline=%3*
    endif
    set statusline+=Here you made your magic status line info text
endfunction
```

then call the function when you load buffer.

#### Edit

add how it worked in terminal:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. Maybe I didn't understand your answer. This didn't work. `set statusline+=%{CheckUtf8()}\ 

function! CheckUtf8()
    if &fenc == "utf-8"     
        set statusline+=%4*\ %{&fenc}\
    else
        set statusline+=%3*\ %{&fenc}\
    endif
    " set statusline+=Here you made your magic status line info text
endfunction`

Comment: don't use `%{CheckUtf8()}\` in `set stl`! you changed my codes. `=` -> `+=` make a small example, test with my codes, it should work.

Comment: I can't make it work. It gives an empty yellow colored statusline with every kind of fileencoding.

Comment: @Remonn add an animation to show how it worked in terminal. (I didn't set gui* colors) but you can see, the color changed.

Comment: Maybe it works in terminal but I can't make it work in gvim. It just returns an empty yellow colored statusline with every kind of fileencoding. :(

Comment: @Remonn they are the same. only the `hi ...` different. I don't want to make another gif to show it will work in gvim.

Comment: Kent, call the function when you load buffer: Do you mean with an autoload command? I just added this in vimrc: `:call MkStatusLine()`, together with the function as indicated above.

Comment: I showed that in the gif, maybe it was too fast? `au BufEnter * call XXX()`

Comment: Yes that did it :) Sorry Kent. I did not note the autocommand.

Comment: There is no problem to call other functions within MkStatusLine()/Fenc() isn't it? p.e. I call a function from the statusline which returns the current language, spellcheck info etc. Is it slower to use an autocommand or is it the same as `set stl`? I don't understand very well the difference between both.

Comment: @Remonn should be fine. do some test